# fullpage.js can't zoom in or out on mobile device

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

i have a question,i use iphone surf [my web](http://www.ee.nsysu.edu.tw/key/c1.php),first page is difficult to zoom in and zoom out on mobile device

i find solution  responsiveWidth:1000, first page can be zoom out and zoom in by mobile,but vertical navigation dot will disppear

i don't know to solve it ,can you give my some way?

thank you

```js
$(window).on( 'load', function () {
 $('#dowebok').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#FFFFFF', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', '#f90'],
         anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page6'],

  navigation: true,
  scrollOverflow:true,
         css3:false,
         resize:true,
         slidesNavigation:true,//水平导航
                controlArrows: false,//隐藏水平箭头
         menu: '#mymenu',
         slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
         responsiveWidth:900,
         //touchScrolling:false     
      
            
 });
 
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll only be able to zoom if you use `autoScrolling:false` or `scrollBar:true`.

The responsive option sets `autoScrolling` to `false` and that's why you are able to do it then.

In any case, it is NOT consider a real responsive website if you have to zoom. So whatever you are trying to do, it is not within the best practises.

Comment: thank you to reply,when autoscrolling set to false,the mobile screen can zoom in and out,but the scrolling can not just stop one page properly sometime it'll stop between first page and second page,i don't know how to solve it. and the first page content of  myweb site  is not over onepage in mobile screen, why can't zoom in or out? thx